# Error in windows(height = 6, width = 8) : could not find function "windows"

Tags: r, macos

I'm start to working on BBMM on my MAC..

I'm trying to running the script from this tutorial: https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Supplement_1_R_source_code_for_the_Brownian_bridge_movement_model_BBMM_that_estimates_a_utilization_distribution_UD_for_a_migration_route_of_a_GPS-collared_mule_deer_as_depicted_in_Fig_2_/3514610

```
density = BrownianBridge(locs$X, locs$Y, Time=locs$Julian, 
            LocationError=20, cell.size=200)
```

when I run this row I have this ERROR :

```
Error in windows(height = 6, width = 8) : 
 could not find function "windows"
```

Someone have this problem too?

Comment: Try running it in base R rather than in RStudio - I seem to recall there's a conflict there. Edit - having tried it, it work fine.  Evidently my memory was faulty.

Answer (score 1):

The `windows()` function is only on Windows, not on Macs. Use `dev.new()` for a platform-independent way to open graphics windows.